# UITableViewCellAutomaticDimension behaves weirdly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with multiple custom cells. The heights for all types of cells are calculated by UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

It works fine when scrolled normally. But when scrolled super fast, it returns weird heights. It again reloads properly after I scroll sometime and get back to it.

I tried to check if the uitableview is scrolling fast and reload table as below:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocityInView(self.view).y < -750
        fastScroll = true
    }
}    

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if fastScroll {
        fastScroll = false
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Though this works fine, I'm not satisfied with this solution. Can someone point me out to the right solution?

Comment: It is funny, but I had exact opposite problem, I have very complex layout in UITableViewCell and I am also using UITableViewCellAutomaticDimension, but when I scroll tableview with medium speed - it returns weird values.

Comment: @PavelGatilov U solved it? Any Suggestions?

Comment: not rly, right now I am trying to do layout in different way, remove complexity.

Answer (score 1):

So this wierdness occur only when i insert or delete cells. I was able to solve this by adding **setNeedsLayout()** and **layoutIfNeeded()**

```
myTableView.beginUpdates()
myTableView.deleteSections(deleteIndexes, withRowAnimation: .None)
myTableView.insertSections(insertIndexes, withRowAnimation: .None)
myTableView.reloadSections(reloadIndexes, withRowAnimation: .None)
myTableView.endUpdates()

myTableView.setNeedsLayout()
myTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```